# Deselect a selected date of range in Time square library of Android

Tags: android, calendar, android-time-square

Here I want to deselect a date of a range which is selected using Time Square library. I'm getting selection of range by:

```
   if (selectionMode == SelectionMode.RANGE && selectedCells.size() > 1) {
    // Select all days in between start and end.
    Date start = selectedCells.get(0).getDate();
    Date end = selectedCells.get(1).getDate();
    selectedCells.get(0).setRangeState(MonthCellDescriptor.RangeState.FIRST);
    selectedCells.get(1).setRangeState(MonthCellDescriptor.RangeState.LAST);
    Log.d("First", MonthCellDescriptor.RangeState.FIRST +"");
    Log.d("Last",MonthCellDescriptor.RangeState.LAST+"");
    for (List<List<MonthCellDescriptor>> month : cells) {
      for (List<MonthCellDescriptor> week : month) {
        for (MonthCellDescriptor singleCell : week) {
          if (singleCell.getDate().after(start)
              && singleCell.getDate().before(end)
              && singleCell.isSelectable()) {
            singleCell.setSelected(true);
            singleCell.setRangeState(MonthCellDescriptor.RangeState.MIDDLE);
            selectedCells.add(singleCell);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And when I try to remove a selected date of range it removes other dates too:

```
    if (selectedCell.getDate().equals(date)) {
    // De-select the currently-selected cell.
    selectedCell.setSelected(false);
    selectedCells.remove(selectedCell);
    date = null;
    break;
   }
```

**Example:**  If selected range is 10 to 30, on tap of 22, 22 should get deselected from that range.